# Convergence of moving point inside of unit disk.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, euclidean-geometry

Suppose Set D :
$$D=\left\{(x, y)\vert x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \right\}$$

And Point $P(0, 0)$ on coordinate plane.

Define 'Movement' :

For a point P, select any direction and move $\frac{1}{2^n}$ to straight (Sorry, my english is poor.) When 'Movement' Execute $n$-th times

---

For example :

$1$st time, Suppose I selected positive-x-axis direction

Then, Point $P(0,0)$ moves to $P\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)$

$2$nd time, Suppose I selected Positive-y-axis direction

Then, Point $P\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$ moves to $P\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4} \right)$

---

If I take $n\longrightarrow\infty$, Arbitrary point $A(x, y)\in D$ can be expressed by 'Movement'?

I Know that perimeter of $x^2+y^2=1$ can be expressed by 'Movement' because $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=1$$

But how about inside of $x^2 + y^2 =1$?

---

**Example**

[image]

The point with $1, 2, 3, 4, \cdots$ is a point which moved by $n$-th 'Movement'

The angle(direction) is free.

the problem is : If $n \longrightarrow\infty$, arbitrary points in $D$ can be expressed by 'Movement'?

Comment: Are we allowed to move in oblique angles?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel , Yes, we can. Just don't move like curve.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I added a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** Not only you *can* do this, it is even possible to move on one line connecting the origin and your point of interest. Maybe not surprisingly, this is related to the binary representation of a number.

Consider a point $p=re^{i\theta}=x+iy$, and let us limit ourselves to movement at angle $\theta$ only (*i.e.* on the line connecting the origin and $p$). Thus, this problem essentially boils down to the question if every number $-1\leq z\leq 1$ can be written as

$$z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\frac{1+a_{n}}{2}}{2^{n-1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{b_{n}}{2^{n-1}}-1=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{c_{n}}{2^{n}}-1$$

with $a_{n}\in\left\{-1,1\right\}$, $b_{n}=\frac{1+a_{n}}{2}\in\left\{0,1\right\}$ and $c_{n}=b_{n+1}\in\left\{0,1\right\}$. Let $q=z+1$, so $0\leq q\leq 2$ and the above condition is

$$q=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{c_{n}}{2^{n}}$$

with $c_{n}\in\left\{0,1\right\}$. But this is just binary representation.

---

**Example 1:** Want to get back to the origin? No problem. Take $z=0$, thus $q=1$ and $c_{n}=\left(1,0,0,\dots\right)\Longrightarrow a_{n}=\left(1,-1,-1,\dots\right)$. In this case $\theta$ is arbitrary so let's walk on the $x$ axis. This means you should go

$$\left(0,0\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4},0\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8},0\right)\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}},0\right)=\left(0,0\right)$$

**Example 2:** Want to go to $\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)$? Take $\theta=0$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}$, thus $q=\frac{3}{2}$ and $c_{n}=\left(1,1,0,0,\dots\right)\Longrightarrow a_{n}=\left(1,1,-1,-1,\dots\right)$. This time your path is

$$\left(0,0\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4},0\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8},0\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16},0\right)\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}},0\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)$$